# New 2.9 Feature: Correct Face Attribute (checkbox) not available in Options Drop-down

Tags: texturing, uv

Now that I'm using Blender 2.9, I've been excited about using the **Correct Face Attributes** checkbox, which will allow me to resize my mesh and have the texture naturally extend (rather than be stretched).

However, when I click on the Options drop-down, I see only the normal Transform checkboxes (Origins, Locations, Parents). But no other options such as when I'm seeing in all these YT vids where people illustrate it.

Is there some new addon that I must activate to add this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: I have been looking for ages for this, not realising it was not in 2.83...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No add-on required - It's under the "Active Tool and Workspace Settings" tab:

[image: Tool]

Bear in mind, you need to be in edit mode for these options to appear - they are not present from object mode (see below). However applying these settings to one object (in edit mode), applies it to all objects in the scene.

[image: NoSelect]

Comment: See, I don't see that. I see this: https://i.ibb.co/9bnkpt6/transform-missing-2020-09-04.png

I'm using 2.90.0

Comment: You have to be in edit mode I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks! That detail solved it.

Comment: I still don't see it.  All I see is mirror and auto merge