# Scale edges symmetrically, preserving UVs

Tags: edges

I want to Edge Slide two Edge loops on Y-axis. Normally, I would press `S` and `Y` to scale on Y-axis but that wouldn't preserve the UVs. And Edge Slide doesn't allow me to slide symmetrically along an axis. Is there a way to achieve that effect using Edge Slide?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hello :). [Since Blender 2.9](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/193474/78972) it does actually update your UVs, so no need for edge slide :).