# Rotating in edit mode meshes messes up UV Maps

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

Every time I rotate any model in the scene the UVs get messed up. I tested doing the same in a new scene and everything works normally.

[image: Before model is rotated]

[image]

Has anyone ever encountered this problem in Blender? Someone using Autodesk had the same issues and resolved the issue by clearing the undo history. Also does anyone know how to clear undo history in blender? Although the same issue was on a different program, it may be worth trying the same thing. I'm using blender 2.92.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the [UNDO] part of the question is separate ... you should place it in a new question. Are you implying that at some point in the UV editor you rotated some faces and the History Buffer is restoring this in UNDO attempts?

Comment: Closely related: [New 2.9 Feature: Correct Face Attribute](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/193474/78972)

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank you soo much! Turning off "Correct Face Attributes" under Active Tool and workspace setting fixed the issue!